# Align two elements horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having problems placing two elements on the same line inside a container. I think I'd better to show you what I mean: http://fillobottosw.altervista.org/

After the expansion is performed, a sort of description is shown on the right side, but out the box, instead of being displayed inside the gray border.
This is what I wrote down so far:

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="tile">
                  <div id="main" width="509" style="float: left;">
                    <img src="images/rbf.png" width="509" height="188">                 
                  </div>

                  <div id="second" width="509" style="float: left;">
                     <p class="description">...text...</p>         
                  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
p.description {
    display: none;
    color: #999;
    float:right; 
    margin-left: 520px;
}

.tile {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #999;
    border-width: 1px;

    height: 188px;
    width: 509px;

    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT** (for expansion)

```
$('.tile').hover(   
  function() {  
        $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({ width: '1100px'}, 600, 'swing',
             function() { $(this).find('.description').fadeIn(700);
         });
  },
  function() {  
     $(this).find('.description').hide();
     $(this).animate({width: '509px'}, 200);  

  }
);
```

Can you please tell me the error I keep doing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues with your HTML and CSS. For one, you have more than one element with the same `id` value. You should probably switch these to classes, or create a unique `id` value for each element. In your CSS, you are floating elements that probably don't need to be floated...and you are mixing inline styles with your external CSS. That's not exactly an issue, but it can cause headaches when trying to troubleshoot.

You're also getting some wonky behavior on your `.hover` event, because the event can fire multiple times before your animation sequences complete.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kbgsP/11/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="main">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/509x188" width="509" height="188" alt="roboform">
    </div>
    <div id="boo" class="second">
        <p class="description"> <b>Roboform Bot</b>
            <br>This bot will speed up the addition process of new idetities. All the identities will match to a fake Italian person. If you don't know the usage of Roboform like to know that it's a software that fill registration fields for you. The trial version lasts for one day only. The full version is priced 4&euro;.</p>
        <div class="LinkButton" onclick="location.href='http://www.fillobottosw.altervista.org/apps/roboform/Roboform_Bot.exe';"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
    <div class="main">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/509x188" width="509" height="188" alt="roboform">
    </div>
    <div id="boo" class="second">
        <p class="description"> <b>Roboform Bot</b>
            <br>This bot will speed up the addition process of new idetities. All the identities will match to a fake Italian person. If you don't know the usage of Roboform like to know that it's a software that fill registration fields for you. The trial version lasts for one day only. The full version is priced 4&euro;.</p>
        <div class="LinkButton" onclick="location.href='http://www.fillobottosw.altervista.org/apps/roboform/Roboform_Bot.exe';"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tile {
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #999;
    height: 188px;
    width: 509px;
    margin: 4px auto 12px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.main, .second {float:left; width:509px;}
.second {margin-left: 12px;}
.second p {color: #999;}
```

**JS:**

```
// hide your descriptions
$('.description').hide();

// track whether or not the user really wants to see the description
var checkIntent = '';
// how long should the user have to hover before you show them the description (in milliseconds)
var waitTime = 500; 

// bind the hover event to all `.tile` elements.
$('.tile').hover(showDescription, hideDescription);

function showDescription(e){
    // wait X seconds before starting the animation sequence
    checkIntent = setTimeout(function() {
        var tile = $(e.currentTarget);
        var descriptionContainer = tile.find('.description');
        descriptionContainer.data('showing', true);
        tile.animate({width:'1100px'}, 300, function(){
            descriptionContainer.fadeIn(300);
        });
    }, waitTime);
}
function hideDescription(e){
    // if the user's mouse leaves the bound element and the timer has not fired,
    // cancel the animation sequence to show the description
    clearTimeout(checkIntent);
    var tile = $(e.currentTarget);
    var descriptionContainer = tile.find('.description');
    // if the description is showing - hide it
    if(descriptionContainer.data('showing')) {
        descriptionContainer.fadeOut(300, function(){
            tile.animate({width:'509px'}, 300);
        });
        descriptionContainer.data('showing',false);
    }

}
```

Comment: This. Didn't know about this, your advice will be very useful for me. Anyway now all the elements below the tile are disappeared.

Comment: I'll work on it and then I'll post here if I keep getting this issue. Thank you

Comment: "When you float elements it pulls them out of the regular DOM flow, so they aren't really being contained as you think." Maybe that's why I'm getting this: http://imgur.com/bmQhHwg . To emulate it, go on my website, place the mouse over one tile, then very quickly go on the second one, on the first again and lastly place the mouse outside of the tiles. You have to ben very fast. I suppose that the problem is now jQuery, which is too slow...

Comment: it's not that jQuery is too slow...it's that you are firing an animation that takes a certain amount of time to complete, and your code can fire that call to `.animate` multiple times. You should probably think about using a `setTimeout` to get a sense of the user's intention before firing the animation request.

Comment: I've updated the top post with a "solution" that still being bugged. It checks if the element is already performing an animation before starting a new one. You code is less "responsive", but I figured out that using little intervals I come across animation problems. I'd like to thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

So just having a quick look, looks like you should add/remove the following

```
.second
{
  float: right;
  width: 509px;
}
```

Then remove

```
margin-left: 520px
```

from p.description so p.description should read

```
p.description
{
  display: none;
  color: #999;
  float: right;
}
```

Then add some padding or something to description to make it sit better,

Hope this helps some what :)

P.S

main div should be float left, second should be float right, no need for display: inline-block

Comment: Your suggestion does the trick, but now another problem comes out. When the tile is collapsed, the white space below it is thicker, secause the "second" div goes under "main" div.

Answer (score 0):

I could not repair your code, so I positioned .description as relative to .tile and it works.

And also I observed that if the content of .description is just one word, then your code seems to work. Dunno why. 
Anyway, [here's the codepen page for edited code.](http://codepen.io/saivineet89/pen/qgiCa)